# Prolog sum of multiples ( recursion)

Tags: prolog

I am trying to solve some problem from my home work in Prolog:
sum of multiples:

for example :

```
multi_sum([[2,3],[5,4],[3,1,2]],X).
```

should return : `X = 32`. but i am getting as a result : `false`.

```
multi([],1).
multi([A|B]|G):-multi(B,Z),G is A * Z.

multi_sum([],0).
multi_sum([A|B],Q):- multi(A,M) , multi_sum(B,T), Q is T + M.
```

Comment: @Boris: I think he made a typo: notice the pipe (`|`) instead of the comma (`,`) in the head of the second line.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yep, that's a typo.

Comment: `multi([2],R)` already fails.

Comment: @Boris yes , thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split the problem into two parts:

- a part that calculates the product of a list of numbers like your `multi/2`; and
- a part that calculates the sum over these products like the `multi_sum/2`.

For your `multi/2`, you made a typo:

```
multi([A|B]|G):-multi(B,Z),G is A * Z.
```

The second pipe (`|`) should be a comma (`,`):

```
multi([A|B],G):-multi(B,Z),G is A * Z.
```

Now it works:

```
?- multi_sum([[2,3],[5,4],[3,1,2]],X).
X = 32.
```

Nevertheless, you can improve efficiency by using *accumulators* and *tail recursion*:

```
multi(L,R) :-
    multi(L,1,R).

multi([],R,R).
multi([A|B],S,R) :-
    T is S*A,
    multi(B,T,R).

multi_sum(L,R) :-
    multi_sum(L,0,R).

multi_sum([],R,R).
multi_sum([A|B],S,R)
    multi(A,Sub),
    T is S+Sub,
    multi_sum(B,T,R).
```

Comment: Not sure about the efficiency claim. It will happen in constant memory with tail-recursion optimization, but I am not sure it will be any faster (in many cases accumulator + tail recursion is actually slower!)